# Display complete comment section via post ID

Tags: comments, comment-form

what I want to achieve:
I would like to display the complete comments (including answers and the comment form) of a certain Page ID in the middle of my home page (I use WPBakery Page Builder). These comments belong to a completely different page.

What I tried:
I created a shortcode snippet.

```
function debatecomment_function ( $atts ) {
    // some stuff to get my page
    if ($page) {
        $page_id =  $page->ID;
    }
    $args2 = array(
        'post_id' => $page_id 
    );
    $comments = get_comments( $args2 );
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    //formating
    }
    $return = $comments_output;

    $args = array();
    $return .= comment_form( $args, $page_id );

    return $return;
}
add_shortcode('debatecomment', 'debatecomment_function');
```

This actually works. But with limitations.
I have to completely recreate the formatting and there are problems with the answer button and so on ...
Is there a way to output the whole comment tree in one piece?

Thanks for any help!